# I am trying to make a script to auto click cards but doesn't work

Tags: javascript, click, element, auto

here is the link im trying to make a click event on using javascript:
[jawaker](https://www.jawaker.com/en/games/complex_complex)

after i join a game it gives me cards, i am trying to make a script to auto click those cards
here is the html:

```
    <div id="card-c966" class="card face-up club-10 ui-draggable">

  
    <div class="face"></div>
    <div class="back"></div>
  
    </div>
```

what i have tried :

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll('[class*="draggable"]');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(a, callback);
 function callback(element, iterator)  {
  console.log(iterator, element.id);
triggerMostButtons (element);
}

function triggerMostButtons (jNode) {
    triggerMouseEvent (jNode, "mouseover");
    triggerMouseEvent (jNode, "mousedown");
    triggerMouseEvent (jNode, "mouseup");
    triggerMouseEvent (jNode, "click");
jNode.click;
jNode.click();
}

function triggerMouseEvent (node, eventType) {
    var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent (eventType, true, true);
    node.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
```

nothing happens except the mouseover, it just hover but doesn't click.
although the element is defined in the variable.

what am i missing !

Answer (score 0):

### The Problem

It seems the problem is related with how quickly you are dispatching those different events in a way that don't really fit with reality considering those are supposed to be mouse events. I tried to add a `delay` function that will pause execution before executing the next statement where you were dispatching the mouse events. It seems to me that now it's behaving better. Maybe try using different timings.. right now I chose 100ms between each event.

By the way as far as I can say, your code has the right intentions, dispatching all the mouse events (mouseover, mousedown, mouseup, click) to the elements having a class containing `draggable`.

## How to show what's going on

To show the evidence of that behaviour I wrapped your code in the `dispatchMouseEventsToDraggableElements` function that is invoked <s>after initalizing a deck with 10 cards created from a template</s> after all mouse events handlers were added to the only card available on the page.

<s>The initialization is performed by `initGame` that also adds listener for those same mouse events to all those cards so that when the event will occur, it will print on console the details about the element triggering event and the event type occurred.</s>

As soon as run, the code will print on console that all those events occurred for the element having the event handlers.

```
0 c01
Event mouseover occurred on #c01!
Event mousedown occurred on #c01!
Event mouseup occurred on #c01!
Event click occurred on #c01!
Event click occurred on #c01!
```

It means that the strategy to dispatch those events ***programmatically*** instead of waiting for them to occur through the user action, ***it's working as expected***.

In case you are going to experience again that it's not working, since it's actually working I will expect to hear something more than *"it's not working"* and why and what exactly it's not behaving as expected.

```js
//initGame();

//add listeners for all the mouse events to the #c01 card
const card = document.getElementById('c01');
card.addEventListener('mouseover',(e)=>{ console.log(`Event ${e.type} occurred on #${e.target.id}!`); });
card.addEventListener('mousedown',(e)=>{ console.log(`Event ${e.type} occurred on #${e.target.id}!`); });
card.addEventListener('mouseup',(e)=>{ console.log(`Event ${e.type} occurred on #${e.target.id}!`); });
card.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{ console.log(`Event ${e.type} occurred on #${e.target.id}!`); });

//dispatch mouse events to the cards in the deck after 2seconds from now
setTimeout( dispatchMouseEventsToDraggableElements, 1000);

//dispatchMouseEventsToDraggableElements();

//initialize the deck with 10 cards and adds mouse event listener to all of them
function initGame(){

  //create 10cards in the deck
  const cardTemplate = document.getElementById('card');
  const deck = document.getElementById('deck');
  for(let i=1;i<=10;i++){
    const card = cardTemplate.content.cloneNode(true);      
    card.querySelector('.number').innerText = i;
    deck.append(card);
    deck.querySelector('.card:last-child').id = `c${i}`;    
  }

  //adds listener for those events to all the draggable elements
  const events = ["mouseover", "mousedown", "mouseup", "click"];
  events.forEach(event=>{
    document.querySelectorAll('[class*="draggable"]')
      .forEach(draggable => {      
        draggable.addEventListener(event,(e)=>{          
          console.log(`event ${e.type} occurred on #${e.target.id}!`);
        });
      });    
  });
}

const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

//Your code dispatching those mouse events to all the draggable elements

function dispatchMouseEventsToDraggableElements(){
  var a = document.querySelectorAll('[class*="draggable"]');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(a, callback);

  function callback(element, iterator) {
    console.log(iterator, element.id);
    triggerMostButtons(element);
  }

  async function triggerMostButtons(jNode) {
    triggerMouseEvent(jNode, "mouseover");
    await delay(100);
    triggerMouseEvent(jNode, "mousedown");
    await delay(100);
    triggerMouseEvent(jNode, "mouseup");
    await delay(100);
    triggerMouseEvent(jNode, "click");
    await delay(100);
    jNode.click;
    await delay(100);
    jNode.click();
  }

  function triggerMouseEvent(node, eventType) {
    var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent(eventType, true, true);
    node.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
  }
}
```

```css
.card{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid lightgray 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: .35em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="deck">
  <div class="card ui-draggable" id="c01">
    <span class="number">1</span>
  </div>
</div>

<template id="card">
  <div class="card ui-draggable">
    <span class="number"></span>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: then what seems to be wrong here !!!
can you check it live on the game ?

Comment: I updated my answer better explaining the fact about the timings. I added some delay and things got much better

Comment: first i don't understand initGame function and what it does to my code !
second, i understand your delay, but consider it's one card, it also not working

Comment: the initGame function acts in 2 stages (each one commented with the description of what it's going to do) and basically it creates the ten cards deck. Anyway I made my answer even simpler.. if you are not clear instead of just saying _"it's not working"_ like you did since the beginning in your question, it will be hard to address the problem